# div transparency and background inherits

Tags: css

I am almost certain that this is not possible to create, but I have to ask. So I have those 3 divs. One is main wrapper, other is green one on the right side, and 3rd is the small one. So what would I like is to make that small div transparent all the way down to wrapper. So that it doesn't have green background, but the smiley one. Don't think it's possible, but then again, I might be wrong. I know I can split the green div in 4 blocks and "wrap" the transparent one, but that won't work because I have `border radius` on the small one.

UPDATED:
http://jsfiddle.net/9hLf8mcu/3/

Comment: I'm thinking that knowing what this is **supposed** to look like and the purpose behind it might be more useful than a description. Do you have a design image?

Comment: As @Paulie_D said, an image would help a lot. Also, a more complete code example if you had one (you mention border-radius, but I see no border-radius in your fiddle)

Comment: Wow, I pasted wrong fiddle... Ok ill make it again, wait.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, sorry for that.

Comment: Well you **could** use the same background image just positioned appropriately - http://jsfiddle.net/9hLf8mcu/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with pure css as you would need to have the green div to be transparent too, which it obviously isn't.  A work around would be to give your small square the same background as the one you want it to have and then use `background-position` to move the image to where you want it

```css
.blue {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.blue,
.same_as_blue {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200/) left top no-repeat;
}

.green {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    float: right    
}

.same_as_blue {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-position: -150px top;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
    <div class="green">
        <div class="same_as_blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Your fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/9hLf8mcu/11/) - If you move the `background:green` you will see the little image matches up nicely

Comment: Yea, that's a good idea, but it wont work when window is getting resized, right? Since image I need would be 100% not fixed amount of pixels.

Comment: ah right, you never said it was responsive.  You could do responsive, you just need a couple of extra divs.  I'll have a go and see if I can show you an updated fiddle

Comment: Well, if you have the time, it would be great, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I couldn't get a pure css solution but this is one with a bit of js that works: http://jsfiddle.net/9hLf8mcu/13/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9hLf8mcu/14/ - responsive width and height (with little square set using  a percentage so it moves up and down as well as left and right)

Comment: Wow man, thank you so much, you are the greatest. I must use this in my project, it would look so great. Once more, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Just add this `background: url('http://superlifestylecoach.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a9506f8e970b01348158e534970c-pi');
    background-position:center right;` to your `.same_as_blue {`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/15zg3dgt/)

Comment: Yea, that can work, gave you upvote but accepted Pete's answer since he wrote it first, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I really like Anthony's answer using the duplicated background. Another solution would be to look into the `clip` and `mask` features of CSS.